# Sending plain text to server with PHP

Tags: php, url

I am sending some plain text to a server using `PHP`. The text is part of a url. As an example, the following plain text:

"Enter text here to vocalize. This is a test."

At the server, the text we see is:
`%3Cp%3EEnter%20text%20here%20to%20vocalize.%20This%20is%20a%20test.%3C%2Fp%3E`

My question(s):
1. Why is the above happening?
2. How can I ensure the text is encoded properly?

Comment: Google on urlencoding and urldecoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs will be encoded automatically by every browser. Take a look at `urlencode` and `urldecode`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php